# How to paginate and listen to the data and cancel unnecessary listeners in flutter effectively?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine I am trying to get an infinite scrolling similar to that of Instagram by paginating the post and I will also be listening to the post detail changes for each post that have been queried.

I start off by querying the first 10 posts:

```
void getPosts(){
postStream =
      firestore.collection('posts')
          .limit(10)
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .snapshots().listen((documentSnapshot) {... code to convert to each doc from JSON..}
}
```

As the user scrolls down, I detect the scroll with the listener and query for more posts

```
void getMorePosts(){
paginatedPostStream =
      firestore.collection('posts')
          .limit(10)
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(lastPostDocSnapshot)
          .snapshots().listen((documentSnapshot) {... code to convert to each doc from JSON..}
}
```

When the user no longer needs these post, I'll cancel the stream in the following way:

```
postStream.cancel();
paginatedPostStream.cancel();
```

However, I realized that doing so only stopped listening to the earliest and latest paginated stream. For example, the user may have queried in the following way

```
10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10
^                   ^
```

but the canceling of stream only applies for the first and last 10 posts queried. How can I more effectively cancel the listener to prevent data leakage?

Any suggestion is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but you'll need to keep a list of all your streams, so that you can cancel each one as they become obsolete.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought initially as well, but I'm not sure because that would mean I have to keep a list of many streams if the user has scrolled a lot. Do you think that is the best practice?

Comment: Best practice is not a thing here, it's just whatever works for your app and your users. If you're worried about keeping too many of these streams, you can just keep the current page, the one before, and the one after, and close all others as they become obsolete.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you will need to manage all streams instead of just the first and last one. If you want to limit the resources being consumed, you will need to close each stream as it becomes obsolete.

There is no single best practice here, but most implementation I know of, implement a virtual window of few (say 3-5) screens full of information. So if in your case you can display 10 documents on the screen at once, you'd keep listeners on 3-5 streams of 10 documents: the information that is currently displayed and 1 or 2 screenfull's up and down. Any stream outside of this virtual window can then be cancelled to reduce resource consumption.